# Swift Package Manger - swift build is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create a package in Swift Package Manager and I'm able to init the package but i'm not able to build,run or test it.

when i enter the `swift build` command i'm getting following error

```
error: signalled(6): xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path output:
```

- I've tried everything like changing to latest toolchain from
  swift.org.
- I've followed all the steps from the swift.org's documentation.

If anyone does know about this then please let me know.

For reference i'm using xcode 10.1(from app store) and MacOS Mojave 10.14.1

Comment: Can you add more information about error to the question?

Comment: i'm only getting this output in the console nothing else. not even with the --verbose.